# Set pitch of a song being played in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, pitch

I need to set the pitch of a song being played in a media player.I know that the Sound Pool helps to set the pitch but I use the MediaPlayer(since I need Reverb effects too) for playing tracks and I need to set the pitch of the track being played now.Any one have any clue?

Comment: It is not possible to set the pitch with the use of Media Player. You can set the pitch in Sound pool.

Comment: But I want Reverb effects too...ie .. I have several switches to adjust the effects.. taht includes pitch,reverb effects,bass boost etc.If I use sound pool I can't access the Reverb effects.

Comment: Hay Sreekant, I am facing same problem. Can you please tell me How did you solved this issue ....?

Answer (score 11):

Android 6.0 adds `PlaybackParams` for `MediaPlayer`. I just tested this in an emulator:

```
String recordingPath = recordingDirectory + File.separator + "music.mp3";
MediaPlayer audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(recordingPath));
audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
PlaybackParams params = new PlaybackParams();
params.setPitch(0.75f);
audioPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params);
audioPlayer.start();
```

Comment: How does the float in setPitch() indicate the change in pitch?

Comment: The pitch value is a frequency ratio, so setPitch(.5) would lower the pitch by an octave. I used the formulas on this page to convert from cents to frequency ratios: http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-centsratio.htm